# PL\SQL Hot do I convert select value to bit flag?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to have pl-sql like the following:

```
SELECT ID FROM some-table WHERE 
  (SELECT MAX(some-expression) FROM another-table = 1) OR
  (some-table.ID IN SELECT (SELECT ID FROM one-more-table))
```

This pseudo-query would select all IDs from some-table if maximum value of some-expression equals 1 (or filter IDs by one-more-table values otherwise)

How do I properly implement this in PL-SQL ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below pl-sql:

```
DECLARE

v_Column1  NUMBER(4);
v_deptno    NUMBER(2);

BEGIN

SELECT MAX(A.DEPTNO)
INTO v_deptno
FROM (SELECT DEPTNO FROM DEPT) A;


SELECT A.EMPNO
INTO v_Column1
FROM EMP A
WHERE  A.DEPTNO=v_deptno
OR
A.EMPNO IN ( SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP_2);

END;
/
```

Comment: The second query will fail when it returns *multiple* rows. You need a `cursor`. First query, can be simply `select max(Deptno) into v_dept_no from dept`